# Как сделать такую сетку Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, sass

Вот макет, в котором указана сетка, ширина макета 1600px, ширина от начала сетки до конца сетки 960px: 
[image: сетка]

сколько я не мучался, сделать такую же сетку у меня не получается, можно через padding отодвинуть лого и отодвинуть ссылки, но когда открываешь через F12 всё равно видно, что сетка не по макету.
у меня получается вот так: 
[image: моя сетка]

вот код, который я написал, так же подключена через sass bootstrap-grid:

```css
* {
  margin: 0; }

.home {
  background-size: 100%;
  height: 670px;
  background-image: url(../img/first-bg1.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding-top: 10px; }
  .home .nav__links a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 13px;
    padding: 10px; }
  .home .nav__links a:hover {
    color: #00e0d0; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru-RU">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display&amp;display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&amp;display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Главная страница</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="keywords" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="home">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row align-items-center">
          <div class="col-md"><img class="logo" src="./img/logo.png" alt="logo"></div>
          <div class="col-md">
            <nav class="nav__links"><a href="">home </a><a href="">about </a><a href="">expertise </a><a href="">teams </a><a href="">works </a><a href="">people say </a><a href="">contact </a></nav>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: а какой bootstrap, 3 или 4

Comment: @Kjuri использую bootstrap 4

Comment: Ширина сетки 960? У вас на скрине блок 1140.

Comment: @Gonzo ширина сетки должна быть не больше 960, но у меня она получается 1140. пробовал перебить max-width в контейнере у бутстрапа, но постоянно возвращается почему-то к исходному значению

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понимаю, вам вместо дефолтной ширины 1110 bootstrpap-4 для lg, нужно сделать 940(+ под 10px padding).
Попробуйте сетку пересобрать и переменные контейнера переопределить. 
Здесь дефолтные переменные сетки:

```
bootstrap-4.0.0\scss\_variables

$container-max-widths: (
  sm: 540px,
  md: 720px,
  lg: 960px,
  xl: 960px
)
```

и еще gutters

```
$grid-gutter-width:           20px
```

можно создать свой variables , где-нибудь у себя подключить и переопределить